# Unreachable Code detected c# beginner

Tags: c#

Hi I'm new to C# and could do with anybody's help on how to discover what the problem is here. I keep getting an error saying that unreachable code was detected under the line '_parcelService' at the bottom.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ABC.Data;
using ABC.Services;
using ABC.Services.Service;
namespace ABC.Controllers
{
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private ParcelService _parcelService;
        public AdminController()
        {
            _parcelService = new ParcelService();
        }

        // GET: Admin
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddParcel()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddParcel(ParcelDetail parcel)
        {
            return View();

            {
                _parcelService.AddParcel(parcel);

                return RedirectToAction("Parcels",
                    new { TrackingID = parcel.TrackingID, controller = "Parcel" });
            }
         }

     }
 }
```

Comment: ...because the method will end at the line `return View();`.  All the code after that line can never execute.

Answer (score 4):

On this line you already returned a result from the action:

```
return View();
```

There cannot be anything after a statement that returns from a function. So just get rid of this line:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddParcel(ParcelDetail parcel)
{
    _parcelService.AddParcel(parcel);

    return RedirectToAction("Parcels",
        new { TrackingID = parcel.TrackingID, controller = "Parcel" });
}
```

Or maybe you wanted to apply some logic that would re-render the same view if the validation of the model fails and otherwise would call to your backend service and redirect:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddParcel(ParcelDetail parcel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // The model that was passed to this action was not valid
        // => Redisplay the same view so that the user can correct
        // the errors
        return View();
    }

    // At this stage we know that the model is valid and we can submit it
    // for processing
    _parcelService.AddParcel(parcel);

    // redirect to a different action by returning the corresponding result
    return RedirectToAction(
        "Parcels",
        new { TrackingID = parcel.TrackingID, controller = "Parcel" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is self explanotary. Below

```
return View()
```

you return a View. Therefore every code after this is not reachable. I think that the correct version of your code is the following:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddParcel(ParcelDetail parcel)
{
    // Here you add the parcel
     _parcelService.AddParcel(parcel);

    // Then you make a redirect to a view that are visible all the parcels.
    return RedirectToAction("Parcels",
    new  
    { 
        TrackingID = parcel.TrackingID, 
        controller = "Parcel" 
    });
}
```

It would be good before you call the `AddParcel` to enforce some validations, like if you object is valid (check Darin'n answer). Provided that the `parcel` you POST passes these validations, then you should call `AddParcel`. Otherwise, you should return to the client the wrong object she posted and explain why is it wrong.

Comment: I can't find anything wrong with your code.. idk why the downvote was applied... so i'll bring it back to normal

Answer (score 0):

```
return View();  // problem here

{
 _parcelService.AddParcel(parcel);

 return RedirectToAction("Parcels",
                new { TrackingID = parcel.TrackingID, controller = "Parcel" });
}
```

That is where your problem lies.  you are returning before your logic (code) is ever hit.  Also you have 2 returns...

So since you have a `return RedirectToAction` you can just delete `return View()`

so the solution:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddParcel(ParcelDetail parcel)
    {
        // return View();  or just delete it.. since there is really no point to keep it commented out.

        {
            _parcelService.AddParcel(parcel);

            return RedirectToAction("Parcels",
                new { TrackingID = parcel.TrackingID, controller = "Parcel" });
        }
     }
```